# Prove the combination of two functions.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

$$f(x)=x-1\;\;\&\;\;
g(x)=\frac x{2x+1}$$

For $f\circ g(x)$, prove that $f\circ g(x)=x$ has no solution,

I was able to expand and reach up to $\frac x{2x+1}-\frac {2x+1}{2x+1}=x$ which ultimately led me to $2x^2+2x-1$ however unable to prove that $f\circ g(x)=x$ has no solution.

Comment: Formatting perhaps? It would really makes things easier.

Comment: What do you mean

Comment: There is a way to write down mathematical expressions in order to avoid confusion. LaTeX

Comment: Everything seems alright still no solution insight

Comment: Note:  I tried to reformat your question, but I really couldn't follow your "expansion".  If you clarify, I will edit accordingly.

Comment: That's because the discriminant of $2x^2+2x-1$ is positive, so there are real roots. So there is a mistake somewhere how you got that quadratic expression

Comment: X/2x+1 - 2x+1/2x+1 =x

Comment: That quadratic is close, but not correct.  $f\circ g(x)=\frac x{2x+1}-1$ so $f\circ g(x)=x\implies \frac x{2x+1}-1=x\implies 2x^2+2x+1=0$.

Comment: Check the discriminant of Lulu's quadratic...

Comment: Your error appears to be in how you add fractions.  $\frac x{2x+1}-\frac {2x+1}{2x+1}=\frac {x-2x-1}{2x+1}=\frac {-x-1}{2x+1}$.

Answer (score 0):

You should get
$$
f(g(x)) = - \frac{x + 1}{2x + 1}
$$
You should then get that $f(g(x)) = x$ holds iff a certain quadratic $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$. However, you list the quadratic $2x^2 + 2x - 1$, which is just slightly off, so see if you can find the mistake in your work.

To show that the quadratic has no real roots (and thus $f(g(x))$ has no solution as a real number $x$), you should take the [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant) $b^2 - 4ac$, and show that it is less than zero.